# Custom Payment Module in After place order getting 400 Bad request.Released magento 2.1.2 but issue is still pending..any idea how to solve it?

Tags: payment-gateway, magento-2.1.1

`Magento-2.1.1 : "400 (Bad Request)"` issue generate while place order using custom payment method not Display Error Message on page.

Error Log also empty..

[image]

Comment: please check log files for the errors and let me know the same to provide you a solution.

Comment: log file in not getting  code error..just normal log generate.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I attempted to create a custom payment method based on various tutorials as each seemed to not work however have got to here where its shown in frontend but just throws above error and nothing logged to exception.log

Answer (score 0):

I Have Fixed The Issue By Editing A Core File `Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement` inside this i have replaced content of function `savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder` with following

> $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod,
>   $billingAddress);
>
> return $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);

(Change : Remove The Try/Catch Block)

Note : Please Use A Plugin To Change Core System

Comment: change core and remove cache but not work..same error

Comment: can you post the error message ?

Comment: above image in define..400 bad request.

Comment: Released magento2.1.2 also this issue there again...any idea how to solve it?

Comment: As far as i know , error messages are not showing  since whole placeOrder status is included in try catch block , if any exception thrown from your custom payment module will be cached  by this o uter try catch and will show specified error not the catched one. ` throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
                $e
            );` . instead of this try to throw the exception itself `Exception $e`.

Comment: Right but the error was not throw in front..error shows the only console log...its not good for a user.