# How to upgrade magento2.0.0 to 2.1.2 in Local Machine

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.1.1

How to upgrade my website to latest release magento-2.1.2 ?

Comment: follow this link :http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html  And http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/cli/cli-rc1-samp.html

Comment: I have no ssh still I have working on a local machine..and also I have to try to upgrade above link but not work for me in local.

Comment: Is this working for you?

Comment: yeh it's working..but some bug not fix in latest Magento like as payment related..like as http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137177/custom-payment-module-in-after-place-order-getting-400-bad-request-released-mage

Answer (score 1):

For composer update (recommended) you can follow steps specified in [this stackexchange thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99813/how-to-update-magento2-from-2-0-0-to-2-0-2) which are also given below.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.2 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/cache var/page_cache
chown -R user:group .
chmod u+x bin/magento
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Does upgrading from older to newer version affects Data Loss? We have to take backup before Upgrading?

Comment: Backup should be taken every time before doing upgrades etc. In my case there was no data loss and site is working normally as it should.

Comment: Ok..Thanx @ Devtype

Comment: Please don't post thanks comments, but instead upvote and accept the answer. So the threads don't get littered but can easily be read with on topic stuff :)

Comment: i also need your help in this issue...http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137177/custom-payment-module-in-after-place-order-getting-400-bad-request-released-mage

Answer (score 1):

Using composer,

Go to your system root using command line,
run below command,

```
composer require "magento/product-community-edition:2.1.2" --no-update
composer update
```

**After complete clean cache, run setup and deploy command**

```
 php bin/magento cache:clean
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: possible in local machine?

Comment: yes you can first try with local machine.